# Calling same onAuthStateChanged listener in multiple screens creates new listeners?

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, react-navigation

I am calling `onAuthStateChanged` in multiple screens of React-Navigation and I would like to know if it creates new listeners or does it reset the older one?

I know I can unsubscribe like below but do I have to just call this listener for ex. in Home screen or do I have to do it for each screen? Remember, in react navigation the class state is not reset when navigating so the listener should remain active even when navigating.

```
const unsubscribe = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user_auth => {
    if (user_auth) {
        this.setState({ current_user_id: user_auth.uid });
        if (!this.state.set_as_favorite) this.getUsersFavorites();
        unsubscribe();
    } else {
        //log out
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each listener is unique, so you need to unsubscribe by calling the function returned when you register the listener.

On the other hand these auth state listeners are client-side only objects. So registering multiple auth-state listeners does not mean that you are connecting to the server multiple times.

In fact, connecting to the server is based on using Firebase Authentication period, and does not depend at all on whether (or how many) auth state listeners there.

Comment: thank you for the explanation! Does it mean that it affects the app anyhow or not?

Comment: What does "it affects the app anyhow" mean?

Comment: I mean, what's the whole point of unsubscribing from listeners?

Comment: It's to stop receiving updates. While the listeners are not huge, they probably do take up some memory, so that's one reason to clean them up. But my personal reason is typically just code cleanness: if I subscribe to auth state chances when I enter a screen, I unsubscribe when I leave that screen. Having balanced code like that, helps for maintainability.

Comment: thanks, I was mainly curious to know if it affects the performance if I keep listeners all over the place listening without unsubscribing, but here is a new question: If I dont unsubscribe a listener and navigate to next page then come back and re-call the same listener, will TWO listeners be actively listening/fetching data from Firestore?

Comment: An `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged` listener listen for **auth state** changes, which has nothing to do with Firestore. But yes, if you attach two listeners - you will get two events on each auth state change.

Comment: yes, but what if I use a onSnapshot listener and if I dont unsubscribe?